# Is "I did whatever I could according to my skills." correct?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

> I did whatever I could according to my skills.

Is the above sentence correct when said to somebody? 
If not how do you express the same thing to someone ?

Comment: In short: *I did my best.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sentence is a little bit of a mouthful.

I would recommend these more idiomatic expressions instead:

> I did my best.
>
> I did the best I could.
>
> I did whatever I could.
>
> I did anything I could.

These expressions mean that you put the **best effort you were capable of** in attempting to do something, even though it **may or may not** end up as a *failure*.